# SQLite Access in Objective-C and Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, sqlite, nsstring

I am in the process of learning Objective-C for Mac/iPhone development and decided to try and write something useful without looking at the bible (Aaron Hillegass: Cocoa Programming 3rd Edition).

I'm writing a simple puzzle game. The data that defines the levels is stored as a string in a SQLite database and read into a level object with this line of code:

```
tempLevel.levelData = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
```

I have two other lines that read in other properties from the database (integers this time, not strings) and they work fine so I am wondering if anyone can help me with the problem.

When this line of code executes I get the following error:
    *** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give. If you need any more information I would be glad to provide it.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using FMDB or PLDatabase -- both nice SQLite wrappers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer, but there's no good reason to deal with sqlite directly when there are some great wrappers available:

http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/resources/sqlite

Comment: There are two reasons for not using a wrapper. Firstly there are quite a few it seems and I have no idea which are good or bad and it is depending on code that I haven't written which is annoying. 

Also I thought that database access was a fairly necessary skill in any language so I thought it a good idea to learn it for Objective-C. I might try a wrapper.

Comment: it's not so much good or bad code as it is about what is basically boilerplate code for sqlite.  it's been done so many times that redoing it yourself will take a lot more time than just finding a decent wrapper so you can focus on your app and sql.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is an error in `compiledStatement`.  As a general point, you should check that you get an actual value from `sqlite3_column_text` first, since getting back `NULL` is often the "correct" response to what you ask for.

Comment: The compiled statement is very simple and works for the other two pieces of data I am retrieving. In column 1 there is string data so therefore it should be returned if the other data is returned. It wouldn't make sense for one part of a record to be returned but not others.

Comment: Regardless, if the problem is not with `compiledStatement`, then it simply lies somewhere else in your call. You're sure that there's a string in column 1?  Have you checked the database using `sqlite3` in the Terminal?  If it is there, then I think we're going to need to see more code, since it's likely something else with the sqlite3 context.